# How to annotate an object which is str or has __str__ in Python?

Tags: python

For one of my function, I want to annotate a parameter which is either `str` or returns a valid string when passed to `str` built-in function.

```
def SomeFunc(param: str | ??) -> None: ...
```

Comment: Every object returns a valid string when passed to `str`. The base `object` class has a `__str__` method.

Comment: A little more info would be nice!

Comment: @interjay Not really. You could return something else in a custom type, in which case `str` raises a TypeError.

Comment: @user2390182 I don't think there's any point in an annotation that says "the user didn't do something silly and arguably buggy (such as returning the wrong type from `__str__`) when defining this class".

Comment: If you want to ensure that something fancier than `object.__str__` is defined, you might want to define your own `Protocol` (with a custom method that provides more guarantees than the default `str()`) and use that.  Otherwise, like interjay said, the correct annotation is simply `object`.

Comment: Would hinting something is an `object` trigger a mypy error when someone created a custom type? Since that custom type wouldn't inherit from `object`?  Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?